# VSCode keyboard shortcut for "maximize" / "normalize" window size

Tags: visual-studio-code

Is there any `VSCode keyboard shortcut` for "maximize" / "normalize" window?

Just like in the gif below, double clicking the tab.

I'm using macOS.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The object that you want to maximize/restore is called an "editor group".

The commands to maximize and restore the active editor group do not have keyboard shortcuts associated but you can associate your favourite combinations using the ["Keyboard Shortcuts"](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/keybindings) functionality of VSCode.

Search for *"View: Maximize Editor Group"* and *"View: Reset Editor Group Sizes"*. You can assign key combinations for one or both of them but they must be different.

Or assign a key combination to *"View: Toggle Editor Group Sizes"* and it does both things (maximize then restore), as displayed in the question.

Comment: Awesome! I added `command+M` for`View: Toggle Editor Group Sizes` and it works just as i wanted! Thanks man!